# SQL = SUM up the TOTAL

Tags: mysql, sql, select, sum

```
Date           Flight ID    Member ID   Seat Type   Seat Price  
2013-07-28     F71498           M69202          Business    RM 40.00

               F73591           M69202          First           RM 50.00
                                M69202          First           RM 50.00

               F71498           M37520          Business    RM 40.00
                                M69202          Business    RM 40.00
                                                            ===============
                                                            Total : ??
                                                            ===============
```

I've tried the following SQL

```
SELECT 
    r.ReservationDate, r.FlightID, r.MemberID, s.SeatType, s.SeatPrice
FROM 
    flight f, reservation r, seat s, member m
WHERE 
    r.FlightID = f.FlightID 
    AND r.SeatID = s.SeatID 
    AND r.MemberID = m.MemberID 
    AND ReservationDate = '2013-07-28' 
    AND s.FlightID = f.FlightID
```

I can generate the report above as it should, but i need help in SUM up the total `SeatPrice`.. May I know how to count the Total? Thx in advanced...=)

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was discontinued with the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (more than **20 years** ago)

Comment: @marc_s Im sorry im newbie to this forum.... can u help me with the SQL on total ?

Comment: It would be helpful to know **what database** you're using - SQL is just the query language - used by many many databases.... is this for MySQL? SQL Server? Oracle? IBM DB2? Interbase? Postgres? Or something else??

Comment: You can do this with a help of `UNION ALL`. You will need to replicate all other columns with placeholders, and make the last column as Total

Comment: @marc_s I'm using MySQL

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly , you want your resultset like below ie with last row having column Total and value of total

```
Date           Flight ID    Member ID   Seat Type   Seat Price  
2013-07-28     F71498        M69202      Business    RM 40.00

2013-07-28     F73591        M69202      First       RM 50.00
2013-07-28     F73591        M69202      First       RM 50.00

2013-07-28     F71498        M37520      Business    RM 40.00
2013-07-28     F71498        M69202      Business    RM 40.00

                                          Total      RM 220.0
```

You can do

```
SELECT 
    r.ReservationDate, r.FlightID, r.MemberID, s.SeatType, s.SeatPrice
FROM 
    flight f, reservation r, seat s, member m
    INNER JOIN reservation r
       ON r.FlightID = f.FlightID 
    INNER JOIN seat s
       ON r.SeatID = s.SeatID 
    INNER JOIN member m
       ON r.MemberID = m.MemberID
WHERE ReservationDate = '2013-07-28' 
      AND s.FlightID = f.FlightID

UNION

SELECT '','','','Total',SUM(s.SeatPrice)
FROM
FROM 
    flight f, reservation r, seat s, member m
    INNER JOIN reservation r
       ON r.FlightID = f.FlightID 
    INNER JOIN seat s
       ON r.SeatID = s.SeatID 
    INNER JOIN member m
       ON r.MemberID = m.MemberID
WHERE ReservationDate = '2013-07-28' 
      AND s.FlightID = f.FlightID
```